# Is it impossible to download file via AJAX call in ASP.NET MVC5?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I know it seems to be better to use normal call instead of AJAX call but for some reason i.e. displaying error message on modal dialog in case a problem during download, I need to download file by using an AJAX call in an MVC5 project. Here is what I did finally after lot of tries:

***View:***

```
<a href="javascript:downloadFile()">Download</a>


function downloadFile() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Experiment/GetFile',
        data: '{id:' + 8 + '}', //For test purpose I used static id
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (returnValue) {
            window.location = '/Experiment/GetFile?id=' + returnValue;
        }
    });
};
```

***Controller:***

In Controller, I have a method something like that, but I am really confused if I should do the same method for AJAX Post and success method or not.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetFile(int id)
{
    var dataContext = repository.FileAttachments.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Id == id);
    if (dataContext == null)
    {      
        return Json(new { success = true, returnValue = "8" });
    }
    else
    {
        return Json(new { success = false, message= "Error..." }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Is there a smart approach to perform this dosnload operation using AJAX call in ASP.NET MVC5?

Comment: Its not clear what the point of this is and why you think you need an ajax call (and just use `data: { id: 8 }` and remove `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',`)

Comment: **1)** Actually I use AJAX call for all of actions in my MVC project and one of the main reason why I wanted to use AJAX is to display error message returned from Controller as JSON. On the other hand, if you suggest me to avoid from AJAX call for file download operations, could you please clarify me shortly about the disadvantages of using it for this scenario? >>>

Comment: **2)** What do you suggest to download file using a link? Should I download  file by calling a Javascript method? Or should I download via HtmlActionlink?

Comment: Typically its called using `Actionlink()` There is no advantage using ajax for this.

Comment: Ok, I shall use it. But I am wondering if it is possible to display a message returned from Controller as JSON or string. To do this, I think AJAX must be used. Is not it?

Comment: Yes, you would need to use the ajax code you are using (just modify `success: function(response) { if (response.success == true) { window.location = '/Experiment/GetFile?id=' + response.returnValue; } else { // do something with response.message }`

Answer (score 0):

You need to return file name or file path 
Example "/file/download.doc" 
And then you need to edit view page like follow

```
<a href="javascript:downloadFile()">Download</a> 
<a href="" id="todownload" download> 
function downloadFile() { 
  $.ajax({ type: 'POST', url: '/Experiment/GetFile', data: '{id:' + 8 + '}', //For test purpose I used static id 
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', dataType: 'json',
  success: function (returnValue)
    $("#todownload").attr('href',returnValue);
    $("#todownload").click();
    } 
  });
};
```